# SQL CLR AppDomain Data Caching & Memory Release

Tags: .net, sql, clr, sqlclr

I have written a C#.Net standalone DLL which I'm using to encrypt data on SQL 2008 R2 tables (running on a 64 bit platform) for performance reasons. This can by quite memory intensive as there may be a lot of rows to get through.

I have integrated this with SQL CLR as an assembly/function and everything is working fine.

This assembly is running with Permission_Set'UNSAFE', but is running as a managed assembly (as reported by sys.dm_clr_loaded_assemblies).

I'm keeping an eye on the memory usage via MS Process Explorer, and the memory usage is increasing each time the function is called, but it is not being released.

From reading the MSDN documentation, the AppDomain caches the data returned from the function for future efficiency. If I unload the assembly, the memory gets released.

I have a few questions:

1. Is there any way of 'flushing' the AppDomain without unloading it?
2. Will all my objects from the DLL marked as 'Dispose' get cleaned up by GC?
3. Does (and this is obviously related to the above!) GC cover SQL Server process space also?

I would really appreciate some help with the above as the online documentation isn't really clear on SQL CLR and memory etc.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Guys - anyone have any thoughts about the above?

Comment: Hi @MKelly, did you get to find how to flush the appdomain? I have the same problem..